# tproxy implementation in userspace

Tags: linux, network-programming, linux-kernel, iptables, transparentproxy

I am using an user space tcp/ip stack for a particular application.

I saw Tproxy support as kernel module, in Linux kernel space stack.
But I need the similar implementation in user space stack.
So that I can learn the current internal working of tproxy. 
Anybody help me to implement it in User Space or please explain the internal working of tproxy stuff, I mean," marking the packets", " twisting the destination ip in ingress and egress flow", "keeping all this in a internal table structure"  etc..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

The [Kernel Documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tproxy.txt) for TProxy is still the best source. Otherwise google spits out a bunch of results for `tproxy documentation` and `tproxy example`.

There are also some projects which have tproxy support. For example the Squid Proxy has support for it and a rather long [wiki page](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/Tproxy4) about it.